# SwiftUI: Update NavigationView after deletion (iPad)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to show the *empty view* (here: `Text("Please select a person.")`) after the deletion of a row has happend on an iPad.

**Currently:** The detail view on an iPad will not get updated after the deletion of an item.
**Expected:** Show the *empty view* after the selected item gets deleted.

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail of \(name)")
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(name: user)) {
                        Text(user)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
            Text("Please select a person.")
        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        users.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

NavigationView example from [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-delete-rows-from-a-list).

In the example below, the detail view is shown correctly after the first launch: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHiHy.png)

But after the deletion of a row, the previously selected detail view (here: `Paul`) is still shown: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjztS.png)

Comment: Please paste the pictures into your question.

Comment: Hi @VillageTech, actually I can not, since this is my first question here and posting images is possible after 10 questions. Sry

Comment: Ok, understand.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 14, deleting an element from a list in a navigation view does not seem to be supported.

The `NavigationLink` type takes an `isActive` binding, but that does not work in the case of deletion. When you receive the `.onDelete` callback it is too late. That `NavigationLink` is not in the list anymore and any change to the binding you passed to it is not going to have any effect.

The workaround is to pass a binding to the `DetailView` with all the elements, so that it can verify if an element is present and display some content accordingly.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var name: String
    @Binding var users: [String]

    var body: some View {
        if users.contains(name) {
            Text("Detail of \(name)")
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(name: user, users: $users)) {
                        Text(user)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        users.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a binding from parent view to manually trigger re-rendering (otherwise the child view won't get notified):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
  var name: String
  @Binding var notifier: Int
  @State var deleted: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Group {
      if !deleted {
        Text("Detail of \(name)")
          .onChange(of: notifier, perform: { _ in deleted = true })
      } else {
        Text("Deleted")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct MainView: View {
  @State private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]
  @State private var deleteNotifier: Int = 0

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
          NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(name: user,
                                                 notifier: $deleteNotifier)) {
            Text(user)
          }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: delete)
      }
      Text("Please select a person.")
    }
  }

  func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    users.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    deleteNotifier += 1
  }
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, adding too many state and binding properties. The same result can be accomplished with a single binding in the `DetailView` with the list of users.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the second choice for the list updating: `index`. That way it will reinforce the refreshing:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(users.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(name: self.users[index])) {
                    Text(self.users[index])
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
        Text("Please select a person.")
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @E.Coms, thank you for your answere. Your example seems to have the same problem: If you select a user and delete it afterwards, the text "Please select a person." will not be shown again. Instead, the name of the previously selected  person will still be presented on the right side of an iPad.

Comment: That’s for the last item

Comment: Seems you are encouraged to use customized views